# Saving full array as txt in python

Tags: python, numpy, librosa

I at the moment trying to sample an audio files and store the information from the sampling into to txt file.

The sampling is done using the [librosa](https://github.com/librosa/librosa).

The problem occurs when i save  it to a file... 
The array doesn't get fully saved, I am only able to view a few of the sampling point, and the rest is dotted.

example:

```
22050.000
[ -8.61534572e-05  -1.64340396e-04  -8.03423245e-05 ...,  -1.40137578e-04
  -3.71412549e-04  -5.04361582e-04]
```

This is how i am doing it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import librosa
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import os



path_train =  "/home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/train"
path_test =  "/home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/test"
dnn_train = "/home/k/kaldi-trunk/dnn/train/"
dnn_test = "/home/k/kaldi-trunk/dnn/test/"
dnn = "/home/k/kaldi-trunk/dnn/"
path  = "/home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/"
train_filelist = path_train+"/wav_train.txt"
test_filelist = path_test+"/wav_test.txt"

    files_train = [f for f in listdir(dnn_train) if isfile(join(dnn_train, f))]
    files_test = [f for f in listdir(dnn_test) if isfile(join(dnn_test, f))]

    os.chdir(dnn_train)
    train = []
    test  = []


    for line in files_train:
        #print dnn_train+line
        y,sr=librosa.core.load(dnn_train+line)
        train.append(y.tolist())

    print "Train done!"

    for line in files_test:
        x,sr=librosa.core.load(dnn_test+line)
        test.append(x.tolist())

    print "Test done!"

    os.chdir(dnn)

    with open('sample_test.txt','wb') as f:
        np.savetxt(f,test)

    with open('sample_train.txt','wb') as f:
        np.savetxt(f,train)
```

anything that could explain why i can't save all the sample point rather than a few?

desired output is two seperate files [sample_test,sample_train]
in which each line contain a list. 
each entry in the list should contain as many decimals, which is why either it would be appreciated having it stored as either float or double.

Comment: Does the file size have any effect on its output?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question.. 
I haven't specified that.

Comment: What format are your expecting `test` and `train` variables to be in? The reason I ask is the code appears to create them as a long list of values, but in the calls to `np.savetxt()` you pass two formating strings `%10s` and `%10.3f`. Are you expecting each item in the list to itself be a list of two items? It might help to remove all other code and just leave a minimum broken example (for example create a random list of appropriate dimensions and try to save that).

Comment: ohh.. test and train is array of array which have float values. 
i want to store them float format

Comment: They are lists, not arrays.  Make them lists and tell us the shape and dtype.

Comment: changed it... added description of what the desired output should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `np.savetxt` should be an array.

Add `test = np.array(test)` before saving the data.

1. This will give an error if the data can not be converted to an array.
2. You can print, for diagnosis, the shape of the array: `print test.shape`

Your output suggests that you have a float and then a list in your data, that are printed instead of the content of a NumPy array.